# Таблица умножения

Tags: php

Помогите написать таблицу умножения с помощью двух циклов while 
что то типа этого 
но второй цикл почему только один раз работает почему ?

```
<? 
$cols=10;
$rows=10;
$td=1;
$tr=1;

echo "<table border='1'>" ;

while($tr<=$rows){
  echo "<tr>" ; 
  while ($td<=$cols)
    {echo "<td>".$tr*$td."</td>";
      $td++; 
    }
  echo "</tr>";
  $tr++ ;
}
echo "</table>" ; 
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто потому что вы не обнуляете $td.
правильно так:

```
<? 
$cols=10;
$rows=10;
$tr=1;

echo "<table border='1'>" ;

while($tr<=$rows){
  echo "<tr>" ; 
  $td=1;
  while ($td<=$cols){
    echo "<td>".$tr*$td."</td>";
    $td++; 
  }
  echo "</tr>";
  $tr++ ;
}
echo "</table>" ; 
?>
```

Comment: спасибо 
долго я мучился

Comment: Когда долго мучаетесь, плюньте на эстетику и выведите все переменные на каждом этапе. Иногда помогает

Comment: спасибо за совет

Answer (score 2):

Вот неплохое решение, правда на 1-й взгляд непонятное и без `while` :)

```
<table>
<?PHP 
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
  echo'<tr>';
  for($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) 
    echo '<td>',$j?$i?$i*$j:$j:$i,'</td>';
  echo'</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: :D
я не на столько нуб так что такие то вещи секу

Comment: Да я ничего не говорю. Просто не часто встретишь вложенные тернарные операторы. Вот как, допустим вы сможете объяснить данную строку ;)

    $j?$i?$i*$j:$j:$i

Comment: это как вопрос звучал ?
тогда что тут объяснять  то? сокращенно ($j true и  $i true) : если   $j то  $i ( в любом случае $i ) если   не $j то $i (в любом случае $j)

Comment: ну да ))) а умножение там для красоты